# R utf-8 and replace a word from a sentence based on ending character

Tags: r, regex, utf-8, data.table, gsub

I have a requirement where I am working on a large data which is having double byte characters, in korean text. i want to look for a character and replace it. In order to display the korean text correctly in the browser I have changed the locale settings in R. But not sure if it gets updated for the code as well. below is my code to change locale to korean and the korean text gets visible properly in viewer, however in console it gives junk character on printing-

`Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "korean")`

My data is in a data.table format that contains a column with text in korean. example -

"광주광역시 동구 제봉로 49 (남동,(지하))"

I want to get rid of the 1st word which ends with "시" character. Then I want to get rid of the "(남동,(지하))" an the end. I was trying gsub, but it does not seem to be working.

`New <- c("광주광역시 동구 제봉로 49 (남동,(지하))")`

`data <- as.data.table(New)`

`data[,New_trunc := gsub("\\b시", "", data$New)]`

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Since I want to search the end of word, I am using \\b and since I want to replace any word ending with "시" character I am giving it as \\b시.....is this not the way to give? How to take care of () at the end of the sentence.

What would be a good source to refer to for regular expressions.

Is a utf-8 setting needed for the script as well?How to do that?

Comment: So, you want to remove that char from the *end* of the word? You need to use `gsub("시\\b","",New)`

Comment: It is not that clear what you want to remove at the end of the string: a space followed with `(`, then 0+ chars other than whitespace, and the final char should be `)`? Or nested `(...(..(.).)..)`? Try `gsub("시\\b|\\s+\\(+\\S*\\)+$","",New)`.

Comment: Try `gsub("시\\b|\\s+\\(+\\S*\\)+$","",New)`

Comment: Another suggestion (sorry, your question is not that clear): `gsub("(*UCP)시\\b|\\s*(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))$", "", New, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you!! This works and meets what I was looking for (1st and 3rd comment). Could you suggest some source which has the list of reg. expression and its uses that can be used in gsub. So though your code has worked for second requirement I am not clear why we are passing so many combination....I want to understand the same as I have many more combination of replacement that I need to do and this understanding would help. Also if you can add this as an answer I can accept the same. Thank you once again for your quick answer!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, just realized that in the 1st case it is only deleting the "시" character and not the complete word. I want to get rid of the complete word that ends with "시". So the complete word "광주광역시" should get deleted. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I updated the answer below. See the bottom for the final single expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to match the letter you have at the *end* of the word, you need to place `\b` (word boundary) *after* the letter, so as to require a transition from a letter to a non-letter (or end of string) after that letter. A PCRE pattern that will handle this is

```
"\\s*\\b\\p{L}*시\\b"
```

**Details**

- `\\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `\\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\\p{L}*` - zero or more letters
- `시` - your specific letter
- `\\b` - end of the word

The second issue is that you need to remove a set of nested parentheses at the end of the string. You need again to rely on the PCRE regex (`perl=TRUE`) that can handle recursion with the help of a subroutine call.

```
> sub("\\s*(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))$", "", New, perl=TRUE)
[1] "광주광역시 동구 제봉로 49"
```

**Details**:

- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))` - Group 1 (will be recursed) matching

  - `\\(` - a literal `(`
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `[^()]++` - 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)` (possessively)
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - a subroutine call that repeats the whole Group 1 subpattern
  - `\\)` - a literal `)`
- `$` - end of string.

Now, if you need to combine both, you would see that R PCRE-powered `gsub` does not handle Unicode chars in the pattern so easily. You must tell it to use Unicode mode with `(*UCP)` PCRE verb.

```
> gsub("(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}*시\\b|\\s*(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))$", "", New, perl=TRUE)
[1] " 동구 제봉로 49"
```

Or using `trimws` to get rid of the leading/trailing whitespace:

```
> trimws(gsub("(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}*시\\b|(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))$", "", New, perl=TRUE))
[1] "동구 제봉로 49"
```

See more details about the verb at [PCRE Man page](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt).

Comment: Thank you very much!! This solve my problem. I wanted to have quick chat? Do you have some time

Comment: Just write here, I will answer when I have time, and I am in a hurry right now.

Comment: I wanted to have some clarity on PCRE usage, as your earlier code was also working. Let me go thru your notes again to understand the benefits.

Comment: PCRE is a wholly different from TRE regex engine. It supports lookarounds, and many more fancy features (like recursion and subroutines), and in some cases is more predictable and reliable.